# Loop over files in a directory and merge them python

Tags: python, csv, io, directory

i have 2 files in a folder called looper:

```
testFile.csv 
file2.csv
```

I want my python code to loop over each file in the folder and merge them all into a single output file. So far, my code is as follows:

```
def combine_csv_files(input_folder_path, output_path):
    fout = open(output_path, "a")
    for file in sorted(os.listdir(input_folder_path)):
        for line in open(file):
            fout.write(line)
```

With this I am getting the error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file2.csv'
```

I don't understand why. 
Also, when I merge these files, I only want to get the column headers for the first file. So I want to merge all the remaining files just form the second row. Please help!

Comment: How do you call your function?

Comment: combine_csv_files('E:\\ProjectOpioid\\Input\\Looper', 'E:\\ProjectOpioid\\Output\\output.csv')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`os.listdir()` returns only file names, to get the full path, use [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join):

```
full_path = os.path.join(input_folder_path, file)
for line in open(full_path):
    fout.write(line)
```

As for your follow-up question about skipping the first line, the simplest way is to use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
from itertools import islice    
for line in islice(open(full_path), 1, None):
    fout.write(line)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm getting this error now: IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: 'E:\\ProjectOpioid\\Input\\Looper\\:'

Comment: @UtsavChatterjee that's interesting, what does `os.listdir(input_folder_path)` return?

Comment: When I use os.listdir(input_folder_path), `for file in sorted(os.listdir(input_folder_path)):
        print file` I get the correct output 'file2.csv
testFile.csv'

Comment: @UtsavChatterjee I've updated the answer, please use it and add `print input_folder_path, file, full_path` if it fails.

Comment: Thanks it worked. But can you tell me how I can skip the first line in each of these files while merging please?

Comment: When I use islice, the subsequent files start adding on the previous file but not from a new line. How do i make sure the next file starts appending from the next line?

Comment: @UtsavChatterjee That may happen if the previous file does not end with `\n` and should not depend on usage of `islice`. You can check if a line endswith `\n` and write it explicitly if not.